# The following packages have unmet dependencies: libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.31-0ubuntu9.1) but 2.31-0ubuntu9 is to be installed

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I have tried almost everything trying to fix the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.31-0ubuntu9.1) but 2.31-0ubuntu9 is to be installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.31-0ubuntu9) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And it won't go away. I can't use apt at all with this error.

***What I have tried:***

cleared the cache
apt --fix-broken install
apt -f install
apt reinstall
apt update --fix-missing
apt clean
apt autoremove
dpkg --configure -a

**Policy**

```
libc6:
  Installed: 2.31-0ubuntu9
  Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.1
  Version table:
     2.31-0ubuntu9.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.31-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libc6:i386:
  Installed: 2.31-0ubuntu9
  Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.1
  Version table:
     2.31-0ubuntu9.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
 *** 2.31-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a 64-bit OS. (Intel CPU)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: No, it did not work. Same error. Thanks though, I think I might of found a way with the post.